# Pandas DataFrame assign hirachic number to element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have the following Dataframe:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  4  9  2
1  2  5  8  7
2  4  6  2  3
3  3  2  7  5
```

I want to assign a number to each element in a row according to it's order.  The result should look like this:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  3  4  2
1  1  2  4  3
2  3  4  1  2
3  2  1  4  3
```

I tried to use the np.argsort function which doesn't work. Does someone know an easy way to to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
df = df.rank(axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  3  4  2
1  1  2  4  3
2  3  4  1  2
3  2  1  4  3
```